Fix rotten bottom of doorframe
Is there a good way to fix the bottom portion of a doorframe which has rotted, without hopefully replacing the entire doorframe?


You have a couple of options.
If the threshold is in good condition, you can use a multitool to cut out the sections and replace it with new wood. Alternatively, remove the existing rotted wood and replace with Automotive Body Filler. Sand, prime and paint to finish.
If the threshold is also affected, remove the damaged wood from the jambs, first. Remove the caulking and or grout from along the face of the threshold. Get a 1 x 2 or 1 x 3 aluminum angle. Cut an fit the angle so that it fits on top of the threshold ( I don't know the condition of the other jamb but I assume it is less affected) and goes underneath the wood to be repaired. Tape the ends of the angle with masking tape and proceed to fill in the damaged jambs with auto filler. Sand, prime and paint. Remove the masking tape. Resurface the joint between the tile and the threshold.

Not a bad process, but missing an important first step.  Water doesn't rot the wood. Microorganisms eat at it.  You should treat the wood with a 50/50 mixture of bleach and water to kill the organisms first.   Allow the wood to dry, then do the repairs.

Maybe the "first, first" step is to ascertain that the moisture problem has been corrected and if not, do so. Replacing the rotten wood only sets it up to happen again if the original moisture problem isn't resolved first.

Thanks for the great answer(s)!  I had feeling filler might be the way to go but didn't know if other people would recommend this.  Never heard of car filler so that might be good to explore.  I'm happy no one says 'replace the whole frame' which my OCD side first directed me to do.
